# Cannot read property 'value' of null and add it in array

Tags: javascript

Cannot read property 'value' of null as simple as that but not working even after
`window.onload = function(){`

what should i do here's my code

```
window.onload = function(){
        var shashank = document.getElementById('shashank').value;
        var kiran = document.getElementById('kiran').value;
        var sumanth = document.getElementById('sumanth').value;
        var arun = document.getElementById('arun').value;

var arr = [shashank,kiran,sumanth,arun];

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', showName);
}
```

html is this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Attendance Sheet</title>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <style>
            #present{
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
          <option value="shashank">Shashank</option>
          <option value="kiran">Kiran</option>
          <option value="sumanth">Sumanth</option>
          <option value="arun">Arun</option>
        </select>
            <button id="present">P</button>
        <button id="btn">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: None of your elements have IDs so obviously `document.getElementById` will not select an element. What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply because you are trying to get element which doesn't have an id, let's take a look at [MDN official documentation for getElementByID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
and look at the fixed sample in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLGZGO)

```
<option id="shashank" value="shashank">Shashank</option>
<option id="kiran" value="kiran">Kiran</option>
<option id="sumanth" value="sumanth">Sumanth</option>
<option id="arun" value="arun">Arun</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your html to inlcude Ids like this:

`<option id="shashank" value="shashank">Shashank</option>`

or you can get the options arr as the following:

```
let options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides your `<option>` tags doesn't have the id's you are trying to access, I think what are you trying to do isn't optimal. What will happen if you have a select with 100 options? I think the best way is to create a `eventListener` for your select and get only the selected option.

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', showName);

  var myOpt = document.getElementById('mySelect').value; // myOpt = shashank

  document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change', function(ev) {       
    // here you can save your selected option and do whatever you want
    myOpt = ev.target.value
  });
}
```

don't forget to add the id `mySelect` in `<select>` tag!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Attendance Sheet</title>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <style>
            #present{
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option id="shashank" value="shashank">Shashank</option>
          <option id="kiran" value="kiran">Kiran</option>
          <option id="sumanth" value="sumanth">Sumanth</option>
          <option id="arun" value="arun">Arun</option>
        </select>
        <button id="present">P</button>
        <button id="btn">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```